# output rails json variables into coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript

Here's my controller response:

```
format.json { render json: @users.to_json(:methods => [:tokens, :value], :include => { :preferences => { :only => [:name] }}) }
```

And here's the coffeescript parsing the results:

```
$ ->
$('.global-search').typeahead([{
    name: 'users',
    remote: {
        url: '/users.json?search=%QUERY'
    },
    header: [].join(''),
    template: [
        '<i class="icon icon-user icon-2x pull-left"></i>',
        '<div>',
        '<p>{{id}}</p>',
        '<p class="descriptor">{{email}}</p>',
        '<p class="descriptor">{{preferences}}{{name}}</p>',
        '</div>'
    ].join(''),
    engine: Hogan
```

I am having difficulties being able to pull the :include "preferences" name value.  Not too sure how to reference it.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: What about `{{preferences.name}}`?

Comment: I get object object so it must be something close to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the tokens to extract the value.

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#datum